# Where do the alternate or expanded crafting rules hide?

Tags: crafting, l5r-4e

In the group I am a player in, I at times do some craft rolls with my samurai. Generally, it's stuff like painting a nice picture for a gift, as that's the one craft I got. However, we got a late addition to the game and the benefits they get for crafting I don't really understand. I am fairly sure that the calculations at least seem correct, but they are most certainly not in the core rulebook, and thus I can't follow their steps and where they get their free raises from.<sup>1</sup>

Are there alternate or expanded crafting rules I miss outside of the core rulebook, similar to the special rules for falconry in the Book of Air?<sup>2</sup>

---

1 - L5R - Core Rulebook, 4th edition, p.258
2 - L5R - The Book of Air, 4th edition, p.120/121

Comment: Afternote: as it turned out, the player noted that they used *something* from 3rd edition, resulting in much of the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic of crafting popped up again and again - and rules for crafting appear together with discussions on crafting.

### Book of Air

#### p.113: Mechanical Options: Kite Making

There's specific rules for making kites, offering values for such devices.

#### p.115: Mechanical Options: Paper Constructs

An alternative to Origami is covered in this sidebar. Paper Constructs are more sculptures of papermachee.

#### p.117: Mechanical Options Instruments

Crafting Instruments is covered in a sidebar, listing TNs and guidelines.

### Book of Earth

#### p.8: Skills of Earth

Craft rolls using stamina are limited and after more than a normal day full of work, special rolls are needed to not ruin the work.

### Book of Fire

#### p.107-121: The world of Fire

Multiple subchapters in this chapter discuss crafting for weapons, charcoal, and glass, but no new specific rules are given besides general time lengths. The chapter also discusses Poetry without giving rules.

### Book of Void

#### p.14: Skills of Void

Void can substitute the normal statistic to create something truely unique.

#### p.195: WATANU-TRAINED (MENTAL)

This grants a bonus to metal crafting rolls. It might inspire to discuss similar backgrounds for other craft skills.

### Book of Water

#### p.11: Skills of Water

The paragraphs discuss Strengh based craft skills as well as evaluating crafted items using investigation with fittng craft specialisations or Craft/Perception rolls.

### Secrets of the Empire, p.240: GM’s Toolbox: Alternate Weapon-Forging Rules

> GMs who wish to allow greater
> flexibility may wish to consider the following optional
> additions to the basic Crafting rules. However, these rules
> have the potential to be abused, and GMs should carefully
> consider their potential impact before allowing them into
> their game.

The one-page chapter offers special weapon modifications when making a new blade.

---

### Non Official Rules

The *Little Truth* book is not an official AEG product for 4th edition as its subtitle is clearly "House Rules for Legend of the Five Rings, 4th Edition". It gathers both the errata, but also has its own, extended craftign rules based on the Sectes of the Empire extension. In Version 1.5.5.4, they are on page 33.